# Correctly interpreting the Pose (Rotation and Translation) after 'recoverPose' from Essential matrix in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, triangulation, 3d-reconstruction, pose-estimation

I have been breaking my head trying to correctly interpret the results of recoverPose from Essential matrix. This is based on original code posted in [How do I estimate positions of two cameras in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906111/how-do-i-estimate-positions-of-two-cameras-in-opencv)

Here are the high level steps I am using: 
1. Detect ORB features in two images 
2. Match featues using BFMatcher 
3. findEssential across two images 
4. recoverPose ie. R,T from the two images 
5. Triangulate the good featues (masked from recoverPose) using the R, T to created 3d point-clouds (landmarks) 
6. As a ground truth, I also extract Chess board corners from the image and triangulate them using the R, T calculated above. A good planar formation for chess board corners indicates that R, T are accurate for triangulation. 
7. Plot everything

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def plot_pose3_on_axes(axes, gRp, origin, axis_length=0.1):
    """Plot a 3D pose on given axis 'axes' with given 'axis_length'."""
    # get rotation and translation (center)
    #gRp = pose.rotation().matrix()  # rotation from pose to global
    #t = pose.translation()
    #origin = np.array([t.x(), t.y(), t.z()])

    # draw the camera axes
    x_axis = origin + gRp[:, 0] * axis_length
    line = np.append(origin, x_axis, axis=0)
    axes.plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], line[:, 2], 'r-')

    y_axis = origin + gRp[:, 1] * axis_length
    line = np.append(origin, y_axis, axis=0)
    axes.plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], line[:, 2], 'g-')

    z_axis = origin + gRp[:, 2] * axis_length
    line = np.append(origin, z_axis, axis=0)
    axes.plot(line[:, 0], line[:, 1], line[:, 2], 'b-')

img1 = cv2.imread('/home/vik748/data/chess_board/GOPR1488.JPG',1)          # queryImage
img2 = cv2.imread('/home/vik748/data/chess_board/GOPR1490.JPG',1)  

fx = 3551.342810
fy = 3522.689669
cx = 2033.513326
cy = 1455.489194

K = np.float64([[fx, 0, cx], 
                [0, fy, cy], 
                [0, 0, 1]])

D = np.float64([-0.276796, 0.113400, -0.000349, -0.000469]);

print(K,D)

# Convert images to greyscale
gr1=cv2.cvtColor(img1,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gr2=cv2.cvtColor(img2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

#Initiate ORB detector
detector = cv2.ORB_create(nfeatures=25000, edgeThreshold=15, patchSize=125, nlevels=32, 
                     fastThreshold=20, scaleFactor=1.2, WTA_K=2,
                     scoreType=cv2.ORB_HARRIS_SCORE, firstLevel=0)

# find the keypoints and descriptors with ORB
kp1, des1 = detector.detectAndCompute(gr1,None)
kp2, des2 = detector.detectAndCompute(gr2,None)

print ("Points detected: ",len(kp1), " and ", len(kp2))

bf = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)

matches = bf.match(des1,des2)
kp1_match = np.array([kp1[mat.queryIdx].pt for mat in matches])
kp2_match = np.array([kp2[mat.trainIdx].pt for mat in matches])

kp1_match_ud = cv2.undistortPoints(np.expand_dims(kp1_match,axis=1),K,D)
kp2_match_ud = cv2.undistortPoints(np.expand_dims(kp2_match,axis=1),K,D)

E, mask_e = cv2.findEssentialMat(kp1_match_ud, kp2_match_ud, focal=1.0, pp=(0., 0.), 
                               method=cv2.RANSAC, prob=0.999, threshold=0.001)

print ("Essential matrix: used ",np.sum(mask_e) ," of total ",len(matches),"matches")

points, R, t, mask_RP = cv2.recoverPose(E, kp1_match_ud, kp2_match_ud, mask=mask_e)
print("points:",points,"\trecover pose mask:",np.sum(mask_RP!=0))
print("R:",R,"t:",t.T)

bool_mask = mask_RP.astype(bool)
img_valid = cv2.drawMatches(gr1,kp1,gr2,kp2,matches, None, 
                            matchColor=(0, 255, 0), 
                            matchesMask=bool_mask.ravel().tolist(), flags=2)

plt.imshow(img_valid)
plt.show()

ret1, corners1 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gr1, (16,9),None)
ret2, corners2 = cv2.findChessboardCorners(gr2, (16,9),None)

corners1_ud = cv2.undistortPoints(corners1,K,D)
corners2_ud = cv2.undistortPoints(corners2,K,D)

#Create 3 x 4 Homogenous Transform
Pose_1 = np.hstack((np.eye(3, 3), np.zeros((3, 1))))
print ("Pose_1: ", Pose_1)
Pose_2 = np.hstack((R, t))
print ("Pose_2: ", Pose_2)

# Points Given in N,1,2 array 
landmarks_hom = cv2.triangulatePoints(Pose_1, Pose_2, 
                                     kp1_match_ud[mask_RP[:,0]==1], 
                                     kp2_match_ud[mask_RP[:,0]==1]).T
landmarks_hom_norm = landmarks_hom /  landmarks_hom[:,-1][:,None]
landmarks = landmarks_hom_norm[:, :3]

corners_hom = cv2.triangulatePoints(Pose_1, Pose_2, corners1_ud, corners2_ud).T
corners_hom_norm = corners_hom /  corners_hom[:,-1][:,None]
corners_12 = corners_hom_norm[:, :3]

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect('equal')         # important!
title = ax.set_title('3D Test')
ax.set_zlim3d(-5,10)

# Plot triangulated featues in Red
graph, = ax.plot(landmarks[:,0], landmarks[:,1], landmarks[:,2], linestyle="", marker="o",color='r')
# Plot triangulated chess board in Green
graph, = ax.plot(corners_12[:,0], corners_12[:,1], corners_12[:,2], linestyle="", marker=".",color='g')

# Plot pose 1
plot_pose3_on_axes(ax,np.eye(3),np.zeros(3)[np.newaxis], axis_length=0.5)
#Plot pose 2
plot_pose3_on_axes(ax, R, t.T, axis_length=1.0)
ax.set_zlim3d(-2,5)
ax.view_init(-70, -90)
plt.show()
```

So as we can see from images 1488 and 1490, the camera is moving to the left - up AND it in pointing down and to the right. However the plot of R and T of the 2nd position reflects something completely different.

[Image matching results](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1R-c1ZJGXMXOFoy3ilM67yYrc4JqpYdCC)

[Camera Pose Plot](https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1DBS2L7CHC0j1Yfr4taVNtFeLw7JISh1F)

I have tried inverting both using R' and -(R')*T, but that doesn't plot correctly either. I have tried a bunch of different combinations, but none seem to make sense.

So what gives???

The python script and test images can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wrYzphphyrFkUIiqXpfm-2mBQsrAN03b).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by taking the inverse of the rotation matrix because the `recoverPose` function defines the rotation and translation in the direction the points move, and not in the direction the camera moves. For more information see [this post](https://answers.opencv.org/question/31421/opencv-3-essentialmatrix-and-recoverpose/).

Comment: Because I am already undistorting the points which makes them normalized.

Answer (score 0):

Why did you use `focal = 1.0` and `pp=(0,0)` in `cv2.findEssentialMat`, When you already defined `fx`, `fy`, `cx`, `cy` in Camera Matrix `'K'`. As per my knowledge, the same `fx`, `fy`, `cx`, and `cy` or `'K'` itself should be used in `cv2.findEssentialMat`. Something like this. Please explain to me if I am wrong. I am also solving the same problem.

```
E, mask_e = cv2.findEssentialMat(kp1_match_ud, kp2_match_ud, cameraMatrix=K, method=cv2.RANSAC, prob=0.999, threshold=0.001)
```

Comment: The lines `kp1_match_ud = cv2.undistortPoints(np.expand_dims(kp1_match,axis=1),K,D)` undistort the coordinates and also normalizes them.  Hence when using undistorted points, you don't need the K matrix.  Also, findessentialMat doesn't take Distortion coefficients D as an input, which is why we have to do it this way.  Hope that clears it up.